# Docker: Running two services with one Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, dockerfile, microservices

I am working on telegram group for premium members in which I have two services, one is monitoring all the joinee and other one is monitoring if any member has expired premium plan so It would kick out that user from the channel. I am very very new to Docker and deployment things. So I am very confused that, to run two processes simultaneously with one Dockerfile. I have tried like this.

here is the file structure:
[image]

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd  TelegramChannelMonitor

pm2 start services/kickNonPremium.js --name  KICK_NONPREMIUM

pm2 start services/monitorTelegramJoinee.js --name  MONITOR_JOINEE
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR ./TelegramChannelMonitor
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

A Docker container only runs one process.  On the other hand, you can run arbitrarily many containers off of a single image, each with a different command.  So the approach I'd take here is to build a single image; as you've shown it, except without the `ENTRYPOINT` line.

```sh
FROM node:12-alpine
# Note that the Dockerfile already puts us in the right directory
WORKDIR /TelegramChannelMonitor
...
# Important: no ENTRYPOINT
# (There can be a default CMD if you think one path is more likely)
```

Then when you want to run this application, run *two* containers, and in each, make the main container command run a different script.

```sh
docker build -t telegram-channel-monitor .
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name kick-non-premium \
  telegram-channel-monitor \
  node services/kickNonPremium.js
docker run -d -p 8081:8080 --name monitor-joined \
  telegram-channel-monitor \
  node services/monitorTelegramJoinee.js
```

You can have a similar setup using Docker Compose.  Set all of the containers to `build: .`, but set a different `command:` for each.

(The reason to avoid `ENTRYPOINT` here is because the syntax to override the command gets very clumsy: you need `--entrypoint node` *before* the image name, but then the rest of the arguments *after* it.  I've also used plain `node` instead of `pm2` since a Docker container provides most of the functionality of a process supervisor; see also [what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together).)

Answer (score 0):

Try pm2 ecosystem for apps(i.e services) declaration and run `pm2` in non-backrgound mode or `pm2-runtime`

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/