# How to use pm-2 docker with multi-stage docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kubernetes-pod, docker-multi-stage-build

I have written a multi-stage dockerfile with pm-2 docker, but when I am trying to run pod with my image, pod crashes,

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.15.1-alpine3.16 as build

ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_OPTIONS --max-old-space-size=4096

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .

RUN apk update && apk add vim jq busybox-extras

RUN npm install pm2 -g 

RUN npm install --save-exact

COPY . .

FROM node:16.15.1-alpine3.16 as main

COPY --from=build /app /

CMD ["pm2-docker", "index.js"]
```

Error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/pm2-docker'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

multi-stage dockerfile written is correct?

Comment: you don't have pm2 installed in main. You have to run npm install pm2 again in main. You have to set a WORKDIR in main too (before the COPY).

Comment: Docker itself provides a lot of the same functionality that pm2 provides, like restarting the application on failure; can you just set `CMD ["node", "index.js"]` without pm2?  Also see [what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together)

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this issue and like @Dr Claw said, adding `npm install -g pm2` in the main image after COPY did the trick. I removed `npm install -g pm2` from the build image