# nodejs works with command node server.js but nnot work with pm2-runtime server.js docker

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I have a node js application as a docker image when I run a container with node server.js it works fine but when I run it with pm2-runtime server.js didn't work fine, although it is installed and configured well, I tried everything but with no benefit [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  I cannot run your Dockerfile, for example, because `docker build` does not accept PNG files.  Can you [edit] your question to include your [mcve] in plain text?

Comment: Docker itself takes on a lot of the responsibilities of a process manager; for example it can restart the container if its main process exits.  Also see [what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together)  If `node server.js` works, can you just use that without the pm2 layer?

Comment: I want to thank you for your reply, I need pm2 as the customer needs it to work in a cluster mode(active: passive), I solved the issue by running CMD in the docker file to be :                             
 ```pm2 start npm  -- run  start ```    instead of ```pm2-runtime start server.js``` and npm start defined in package.json