# Docker Container Exits Immediately - Node.js Application with Docker and PM2

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I'm trying to run a Node.js application in a Docker container using PM2, but the container exits immediately after starting. I can build the Docker image without any issues, and I'm able to run a container. However, I'm having trouble keeping the container running, and there are no error logs to help me diagnose the problem. Can someone help me figure out why my container is exiting?

the application is working as expected, but not through docker.

my docker file

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

RUN npm install -g pm2

CMD ["pm2","start","ecosystem.config.js"]
```

this is how I am creating a container.

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 naveedalirehmani/bookings
```

Logs
[image]

Comment: It looks like using `pm2-runtime` will work better; plain `pm2` will launch a background process but Docker needs a foreground process.  Also consider [what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together) since Docker can also restart the main container process on failure.