# Multiple PM2 errors when logging my Node.js app pod which used to run fine

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, pm2

I'm getting all sorts of errors related to PM2 not finding some files when printing the logs for my Node.js app pod running on Kubernetes but I have no idea of what can be causing it as it use to run without problem up until last time I checked (used to run on Hetzner cloud on k3s cluster) so I'm not sure when this started.
Not sure it's k3d related, but I'm running it in a local k3d cluster with the same k3s version I used in the Hetzner cloud.

The pod's logs are:

```
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1385:3)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:48:10)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:52:43)
    at mkdirpNativeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-native.js:33:14)
    at Function.mkdirpSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:21:7)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:133:25)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1385:3)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:48:10)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:52:43)
    at mkdirpNativeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-native.js:33:14)
    at Function.mkdirpSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:21:7)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:141:25)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.pm2/module_conf.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2212:35)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:149:10)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1385:3)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:48:10)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:52:43)
    at mkdirpNativeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-native.js:33:14)
    at Function.mkdirpSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:21:7)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:157:25)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.pm2/module_conf.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:459:35)
    at Configuration.getAllSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Configuration.js:299:26)
    at Configuration.getSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Configuration.js:270:30)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:116:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1385:3)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:48:10)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:52:43)
    at mkdirpNativeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-native.js:33:14)
    at Function.mkdirpSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:21:7)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:133:25)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.instanciate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:65:16)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:48:13)
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1385:3)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:48:10)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:52:43)
    at mkdirpNativeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-native.js:33:14)
    at Function.mkdirpSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:21:7)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:141:25)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.instanciate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:65:16)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:48:13)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.pm2/module_conf.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2212:35)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:149:10)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.instanciate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:65:16)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:48:13)
    at Command.listener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Command.parseArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/commander/index.js:653:12)
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.pm2'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1385:3)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:48:10)
    at mkdirpManualSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-manual.js:52:43)
    at mkdirpNativeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/lib/mkdirp-native.js:33:14)
    at Function.mkdirpSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:21:7)
    at Client.initFileStructure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:157:25)
    at new module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:38:8)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:107:19)
    at Object.instanciate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:65:16)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:48:13)
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.pm2/module_conf.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:459:35)
    at Configuration.getAllSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Configuration.js:299:26)
    at Configuration.getSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Configuration.js:270:30)
    at new API (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API.js:116:44)
    at Object.instanciate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:65:16)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/binaries/Runtime4Docker.js:48:13)
    at Command.listener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
    at Command.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Command.parseArgs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/commander/index.js:653:12)
2023-10-31T15:08:46: PM2 error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.pm2/module_conf.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:459:35)
    at Configuration.getAllSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Configuration.js:299:26)
    at Configuration.getSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Configuration.js:270:30)
    at God.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God.js:71:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/God.js:574:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
2023-10-31T15:08:46: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2023-10-31T15:08:46: PM2 error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.pm2/pm2.pid'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:591:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2212:35)
    at Daemon.innerStart (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Daemon.js:91:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:78:14
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Client.js:321:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

If I exec into the pod's container and look for those files I do not find them but I have changed nothing to the Docker file which creates the image nor to the Node.js app itself and in fact from the terminal I can use pm2 to run the app and it runs it fine.

```
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % pm2 start server.js
[PM2] Starting /Volumes/ProjectsSSD/2 - FixitServer/Server/server-node/server.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ server    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 64657    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 24.3mb   │ vin… │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[PM2][WARN] Current process list is not synchronized with saved list. App sendRepairData differs. Type 'pm2 save' to synchronize.
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % pm2 stop

  error: missing required argument `id|name|namespace|all|json|stdin'

vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % pm2 stop 0
[PM2] Applying action stopProcessId on app [0](ids: [ '0' ])
[PM2] [server](0) ✓
┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ server    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 0    │ stopped   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ vin… │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[PM2][WARN] Current process list is not synchronized with saved list. App sendRepairData differs. Type 'pm2 save' to synchronize.
vincenzocalia@vincenzos-MacBook-Air server-node % pm2 save
[PM2] Saving current process list...
[PM2] Successfully saved in /Users/vincenzocalia/.pm2/dump.pm2
```

As it has to run in a container I am using the pm2-runtime to start the app as per docs.
This is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.3.0
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ package.json ./
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true

# Istall the dependencies
RUN npm install pm2 --location=global

RUN npm install
# Bundle/copy app source code 
COPY ./ ./


ENV CI=true
ENV WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0

# commands to execute when the image starts 
# CMD ["npm", "start"]
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "server.js"]
```

and this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "fixit_server_node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "cheerio": "*",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-promise-router": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
    "geolocation-utils": "^1.2.5",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jsdom": "^17.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.1",
    "neo4j-driver": "^5.0.1",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "pg-promise": "^10.10.1",
    "puppeteer": "^15.3.2",
    "sitemap": "^7.1.1",
    "stripe": "^8.153.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

Can you spot anything wrong? Any hint on debugging it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you actually need pm2 here?  ([what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together))  Is it possibly trying to write into `$HOME`, which isn't necessarily defined here?  Is something in your Kubernetes deployment spec either setting a non-root user or a read-only container filesystem?

Comment: @David Maze Hi David, I know, Ionly use it so I can deploy server, mongo db and neo4j within an Helm umbrella chart, and the js divers for both db will throw error so pm2 restarts the app until both dbs are available. otherwise I would have to spin both dbs and only then deploy the Node.js server (haven't found a better solution to this timing problem). As for `non-root user or a read-only container filesystem` yeap I set the whole lot and indeed is the only change I've made.. k8s security.. so by your question I guess that pm2 needs to run as root user and/or write to the file system ?

Comment: @DavidMaze Indeed removing the container's securityContext from its specs makes it work as expected again, while pod's securityContext doesn't affect it at all. So I guess I am to choose if applying security best practices and manually install the charts in sequence or keep using PM2.. well I guess it's time to kiss goodbye PM2 then..
Thank you very much again.

Comment: Kubernetes can also restart the container itself under these circumstances (and indeed "crash if the database dependency isn't ready yet" is probably the easiest thing to do).

Comment: @DavidMaze so just starting the image with `CMD ["node", "server.js"] instead of CMD ["pm2-runtime", "server.js"] correct ? when the error from both drivers gets re thrown it will just make the container fail correct? This should give me the same restarting behaviour I was obtaining from PM2, but instead of having the container always up and the app restarted upon error, I will get the container restarted. I'm trying this setup and it indeed restarts ( 7 times in 12 minutes).