# Hello-world express app is taking 10 seconds to load in Docker on Mac?

Tags: node.js, docker, performance, pm2

I have a ~2GB Docker image (mostly a bunch of CLI tools), and Node.js installed on it (Ubuntu 24.04).

Then I have a simple hello world Express app running through [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) so if it crashes, it restarts. It is using TypeScript so I watch the source folder and compile to the dist folder, and the pm2 automatically restarts the app on any changes to the .js files.

```
import express from 'express'

const app = express()
const port = 4000

app.get('/healthz', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('healthy!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

[image]

But this is even *after* I have reloaded/refreshed that `/healthz` URL multiple times. The very first time, it takes maybe 30 seconds to load.

I just did another test after adding a quick `console.log('ping')` inside that route (causing pm2 to restart the app), and it took 12 seconds to log the `ping` on the server, and 42 seconds for the response to come back!

[image]

```
app.get('/healthz', (req, res) => {
  console.log('ping')
  res.status(200).send('healthy')
})
```

What are the key things that could be causing this to be slow, and how can I improve performance?

My thoughts so far:

1. Syncing the .js files to docker from when I change them is causing some slowness (though the app starts to restart almost instantly on file change).
2. The docker is `eval-ing` the JS from outside itself maybe?
3. `pm2` is slow? I haven't found much here, but maybe it is intercepting every request in a proxy sort of thing, and that is very slow going through docker.
4. I have to change some of my global docker settings to speed things up somehow.

I haven't changed my docker settings from the default on my Mac M3.

[image]

Do you have any other ideas why it could be so slow and potentially what can be done to make the request/response faster?

Comment: Docker can restart the process on its own, and you probably don't need pm2 ([what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together)).  You hint at "watching the source folder", which implies a potentially-slow Docker bind mount, and if the application isn't built until the first call, that's another potential delay.  Can you `RUN npm run build` or similar in your Dockerfile, and avoid bind-mounting host code over the built image content?