# deploy Nextjs(which includes api) with nginx, do I need pm2?

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js, pm2

I know how to dockerize and deploy react frontend.

`npm run build` will create artifacts for react app and served by nginx which is pulled in a dockerfile.

Now for NextJS since the UI and api is in the same application. If I serve the contents(by nginx)  of `.next` folder where NextJs outputs the build,will both UI and api work?

I am having second thoughts about if `api` will work?

Do I nedd pm2 for the api to be running? or just the Nginx is enough?

Comment: When you build a Next.js app, it creates the .next folder which contains both the frontend and the API server. You can serve this folder using Nginx, but the API might not work. When you run the app using `npm run start,` it starts both the front and the API server.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to clarify the specific problem you're having?  It seems like your core question is "will the API part work", and that's a little hard to tell without seeing a [mcve].  On pm2, also see [what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together)

Comment: @Echo 
so yes I understand there will be `.next` folder after `next build` command. So when nginx serves this built, the pages and UI will work. what about the api call that UI makes to backend, will those api work?

Comment: @tigert Yes it should