# How to start Node.js' pm2 on Google Cloud, it keeps restarting with "My job here is done, next job in 30 seconds"?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, pm2

I have a simple express app which gets started through [`pm2`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/):

```
pnpm pm2 start --no-automation --name myorganization --no-daemon host/code/index.js
```

Locally I start it with the `--watch` arg:

```
pnpm pm2 start --watch --no-automation --name myorganization --no-daemon host/code/index.js
```

Locally, it works fine. But on Google Cloud, it appears to be restarting in the middle of requests for some unknown reason. Any ideas why pm2 might be restarting periodically on Google Cloud (but not locally) using a Docker container? I am not sure yet. Here are the logs:

```
> pnpm pm2 start --no-automation --name myorganization --no-daemon host/code/index.js
pm2:paths pm2 home resolved to /home/.pm2 /home
pm2:conf Using 2 parallelism (CONCURRENT_ACTIONS)
                        -------------
__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\\____________/\\\\____/\\\\\\\\\_____
_\/\\\/////////\\\_\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\__/\\\///////\\\___
  _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\///______\//\\\__
  _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\/__\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\___________/\\\/___
    _\/\\\/////////____\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\________/\\\//_____
    _\/\\\_____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_____/\\\//________
      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\___/\\\/___________
      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_
        _\///______________\///______________\///__\///////////////__

                          Runtime Edition
        PM2 is a Production Process Manager for Node.js applications
                    with a built-in Load Balancer.
                Start and Daemonize any application:
                $ pm2 start app.js
                Load Balance 4 instances of api.js:
                $ pm2 start api.js -i 4
                Monitor in production:
                $ pm2 monitor
                Make pm2 auto-boot at server restart:
                $ pm2 startup
                To go further checkout:
                http://pm2.io/
                        -------------
pm2:client Using RPC file /home/.pm2/rpc.sock
pm2:client Using PUB file /home/.pm2/pub.sock
interactor:client [PING INTERACTOR] Trying to connect to Interactor daemon
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/interactor.sock
pm2 launched in no-daemon mode (you can add DEBUG="*" env variable to get more messages)
pm2:client Using RPC file /home/.pm2/rpc.sock
pm2:client Using PUB file /home/.pm2/pub.sock
interactor:client [PING INTERACTOR] Trying to connect to Interactor daemon
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/interactor.sock
pm2:client [PING PM2] Trying to connect to server
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
axon:sock error ENOENT
axon:sock ignored ENOENT
axon:sock error ENOENT
axon:sock ignored ENOENT
axon:sock error ENOENT
axon:sock ignored ENOENT
axon:sock attempting reconnect
axon:sock closing
axon:sock closing 0 connections
pm2:client Daemon not launched
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
axon:sock bind null:/home/.pm2/pub.sock
axon:sock bind null:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
interactor:client Interaction file does not exists
interactor:client Secret key is not defined in configuration {
  version_management: { active: true },
  public_key: undefined,
  secret_key: undefined,
  machine_name: 'localhost-1234',
  pm2_version: '5.3.1',
  reverse_interact: true,
  info_node: 'https://root.keymetrics.io'
}
pm2:client Launching RPC client on socket file /home/.pm2/rpc.sock
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
axon:sock attempting reconnect
axon:sock closing
axon:sock closing 0 connections
interactor:client Interactor Daemon not launched
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/interactor.sock
axon:sock attempting reconnect
axon:sock closing
axon:sock closing 0 connections
interactor:client Interactor Daemon not launched
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/interactor.sock
axon:sock error ENOENT
axon:sock ignored ENOENT
axon:sock error ENOENT
axon:sock ignored ENOENT
axon:sock error ENOENT
axon:sock ignored ENOENT
axon:sock accept /home/.pm2/rpc.sock
axon:sock add socket 0
axon:sock connect
axon:sock add socket 0
axon:queue flush 0 messages
pm2:client RPC Connected to Daemon
pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getVersion on rpc socket:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2 log: [PM2] Starting /home/app/host/code/index.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:prepare on rpc socket:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
PM2 log: App [myorganization:0] starting in -fork mode-
pm2:fork_mode stds: {"out":"/home/.pm2/logs/myorganization-out.log","err":"/home/.pm2/logs/myorganization-error.log"}
PM2 log: App [myorganization:0] online
PM2 log: [PM2] Done.
pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /home/app/host/code/
pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /home/app/host/
pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /home/app/
PM2 log: ┌────┬─────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
        │ id │ name            │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
        ├────┼─────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
        │ 0  │ myorganization    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 39       │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 41.2mb   │ root     │ disabled │
        └────┴─────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Continue to stream logs
PM2 log: [--no-daemon] Exit on target PM2 exit pid=23
pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock
pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /home/
pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /
axon:sock connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/pub.sock
pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /
axon:sock accept /home/.pm2/pub.sock
axon:sock add socket 0
axon:sock connect
axon:sock add socket 0
axon:sub subscribe to "log:*"
task.surf App listening on port 8080
Default STARTUP TCP probe succeeded after 1 attempt for container "placeholder-1" on port 8080.
pm2:worker [PM2][WORKER] Processing proc id: 0
pm2:worker [PM2][WORKER] My job here is done, next job in 30 seconds
pm2:worker [PM2][WORKER] Processing proc id: 0
pm2:worker [PM2][WORKER] My job here is done, next job in 30 seconds
```

Specifically the last one keeps on repeating after a while:

```
[PM2][WORKER] My job here is done, next job in 30 seconds
```

**Of note**:

- I am running this in a **Linux amd64 Docker container**.
- Using **Node.js v20.11.0**.
- **pm2 v5.3.1**.
- Built on Google Cloud using **Google Cloud Build**.
- Run on Google Cloud using **Google Cloud Run**.
- My **compiled JS (from TypeScript) is under `/home/app/host/code`**.

Some things I notice from the logs:

- `Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /home/app/host/code/`
- `rpc socket:/home/.pm2/rpc.sock`
- `connect attempt null:/home/.pm2/interactor.sock`
- `error ENOENT; ignored ENOENT`

Any ideas what is going on? How do I get this working on Google Cloud? Should I even be running with `--no-daemon`? Or is that just a local development thing?

Google Cloud run is a "serverless" system, so do I even need `pm2`? I only added it because I thought "if the server crashes, it should automatically restart", but maybe serverless handles that already?

Comment: PM2 has a default Load Balancer and a default Auto Restart option. Have you tried to disable both of this features? Also try downgrading `pm2`. Have you tried running on `App Engine`? Is there any specific approach for using `Cloud run`?

Comment: @RoopaM I have already invested in Cloud Run for serverless scalability. Can you show how to disable those features?

Comment: Try using [`--no-autorestart`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) flag  also have a look at [Auto restart apps on file change](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/#auto-restart-apps-on-file-change).

Comment: You say you're running this in a container.  Docker can already restart the main container process if it exits; also see [what is the point of using pm2 and docker together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51191378/what-is-the-point-of-using-pm2-and-docker-together)  You're showing this in the form of shell commands, but I'd expect a normal Docker flow to have the `node index.js` or similar command as the image's default `CMD`, and not need an interactive shell at all.